# Python Dictionary of lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I would like to be able to access data from a file, organizing them into a structure that I think should be a dictionary of lists of dictionaries, from what I understand, probably like the following:

```
ID_FILE = { 
        'KEY_1': [
                    {
                        'R_1': [
                                {
                                    'A_1': [
                                            {
                                                'P_1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            }
                                        ],
                                    'A_2': [
                                            {
                                                'P_1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            }
                                        ],
                                    'A_3': [
                                            {
                                                'P_1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            }
                                        ]
                                }
                            ],
                        'R_2': [
                                {
                                    'A_1': [
                                            {
                                                'P_1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            }
                                        ],
                                    'A_2': [
                                            {
                                                'P_1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            }
                                        ],
                                    'A_3': [
                                            {
                                                'P_1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            }
                                        ]
                                }
                        ],
                        'R_3': [
                                {
                                    'A_1': [
                                            {
                                                'P_1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            }
                                        ],
                                    'A_2': [
                                            {
                                                'P_1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            }
                                        ],
                                    'A_3': [
                                            {
                                                'P_1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            },
                                            {
                                                'P_3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                                            }
                                        ]
                                }
                        ]
                    }
                ],

        'KEY_2': [...as 'KEY_1'...],

        'KEY_3': [...as 'KEY_1'...]
    }
```

I do not know whether it is ideally correct, but in practice I would be able to access the dictionary's data with a command like `['ID_FILE']['KEY_1']['R_2']['A_3']['P_2'].b`, for example (using square brackets to select dictionary's key, and a dot for the wanted value outside the brackets) to know the `b` value of `P_2` key, for `A_3` in `R_2` of `KEY_1`, or `['ID_FILE']['KEY_1'].R_2` and get a list `['A_1', 'A_2' , 'A_3']`, that is, select the dictionary's keys, indicating, at the end, the desired information, to get the final output ...

The structure is quite complex, but the concept is generalizable, and I would understand by what method, python module or best approach, I can achieve this in python; if it would be preferred to start from the outside or from within, to organize and concatenate dictionaries into the unique big dictionary...

**Edit 1:** That is, use the value of previous key as key for a new sub dictionary.

**Edit 2:** The source file is a CIF file like [this](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat=cif&compression=NO&structureId=4TVX) (it's a big file with 170925 rows). Considering that cif file, I'm analyzing the lines starting with ATOM, dividing them into columns:

```
KEY = column 6
R = column 8
A = column 3
P = Atom row = list of columns
a = column 1
b = column 2
c = column 3
d = column 4
```

So, for example, to get the x coordinate (column 10) of atom N (column 3) of residue 271 (column 8) of chain A (column 6), give a command like that ['4tvx']['A']['271']['N'].coordX

Comment: This couldn't be explained with a *smaller sample dataset*?

Comment: Please edit your question properly. I got bored by seeing it.

Comment: Attribute look-up like `d[ID_FILE][KEY_1][R_2][A_3][P_2]` won't work with all of those intermediate lists (assuming  those names represent strings).

Comment: In what format does the data currently exist?  You've given a (complex) structure you want, but not the source.

Comment: Create a recursive function and try to have a single dictionary for your structure. First you start with one data set to make it simple.

Comment: Don't roll your own solution for a solved problem.  Use [PyCifRW](https://bitbucket.org/jamesrhester/pycifrw/overview).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I did not know about PyCifRW, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  Steven Rumbalski to indicate to me that tool, [PyCifRW](https://bitbucket.org/jamesrhester/pycifrw/overview), but, answering to my topic's question, the needed structure is a dictionary of dictionaries, to achieve that gool:

```
r_list = ['20', '21']
dictionary = {}
r_dict = {}
a_dict = {}
for r in range(0,len(r_list)):
    r = r_list[r]
    dictionary['C'] = r_dict
    r_dict[r] = a_dict

print dictionary
print dictionary['C']

"""output:

{'C': {'20': {}, '21': {}}}
{'20': {}, '21': {}}

equal to:

dictionary = {'C': {
                    '20': {},
                    '21': {}
                }
            }
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your schema is not ideal (although it is difficult to tell without understanding what you are storing). From looking at your data, KEY_1, R_1, and A_1 should be dictionaries rather than lists. By simplifying your structure, you will be to use [ID_FILE][KEY_1][R_2][A_3][P_2].b

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment than as an answer.